# beamer: How to get tikz spy overlay on top of the other content of a frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

The problem is as follows:
On a slide, I have several figures. I would like to zoom into whole figures or parts of them susequently. I tried to do so using `tikz` `spy` library with the `spy using overlays`-option for the tikzpicture. In principle, this works. The desired area of the figure is zoomed to the desired position on the slide, only it is drawn beneath the other content of the frame, meaning in the background. How can I get the zoomed content to the front? The following MWE illustrates the problem (graphics are included in the `mwe`-package).

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.6\textwidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
      spy using overlays
     ]
     \node[inner sep=0pt]{\pgfimage[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}};
     \only<2>{\spy[overlay,width=7cm,height=2cm,magnification=2] on (0,0) in node[] at (2,-3);}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     some description

     \includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}

     some description
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[r]{0.35\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}

     some description
    \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not placing the spy in node on the background. However, it is only in the foreground *within its enclosing `tikzpicture` environment*. So the 2 pictures which you include *after* the `tikzpicture` are place on top of the contents of that environment, since it overlaps with them. So, either you need to arrange the contents of the frame so that this does not happen. Or you need to arrange things so that the `tikzpicture` is added *after* the other images have been included.

Comment: Arranging the content differently is no option, since I intend to zoom into the other two figures as well. The latter option was what I was actually thinking about. But I have no idea how to achieve that. `tikzmark` also does not help.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you could do something like this (needs a bit of polishing but I'm assuming these are not your actual images anyway):

```
  \begin{frame}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        spy using overlays
        ]
        \node (pic1) [inner sep=0pt] {\pgfimage[width=0.588\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}};
        \only<2>{
          \spy[overlay,width=7cm,height=2cm,magnification=2] on (0,0) in node[] at (2,-3);
        }
        \node [anchor=north, yshift=-.5pt] at (pic1.south) {some description};

        \node (pic2) [inner sep=0pt, anchor=north, yshift=-17.5pt] at (pic1.south) {\includegraphics[width=0.588\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}};
        \node [anchor=north, yshift=-.5pt] at (pic2.south) {some description};

        \node (pic3) [inner sep=0pt, anchor=west, xshift=20pt] at (pic1.south east) {\includegraphics[width=0.343\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}};
        \node [anchor=north, yshift=-.5pt] at (pic3.south) {some description};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
```

[image: spy in in foreground]

Comment: This will work for the specific example. However, you loose the benefits from the minipages (like formating and line breakes) and you cannot combine it with other beamer objects like blocks etc. The best way would be to reserve the required space for the first graphic, but to place it last

Comment: @Janek Use `\phatom{}` then? But I'm not sure how that would work if you want to zoom into all 3 since you cannot place all of them last!